# Is DNS flushing at startup good?

Tags: dns

Is it beneficial if I create a startup command file that contains DNS flashing? Please see image.

[image]

Comment: question is vague

Comment: this will be entirely based on your needs. I would only do so in an environment where DNS servers or entries are being changed very regularly. for instance an advanced virtualization scenario where hosts are being created, destroyed, and recreated repeatedly and rapidly. In most other circumstances, you are forgoing the performance improvement the DNS cache provides, and making more requests to public servers, and thus may have an impact on your privacy footprint.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is not very clear.  It sounds like you want to run `ipconfig /flushdns` at computer startup.

If that is the case, then no, there is no benefit.  Upon booting, your computer has no DNS records stored, so flushing them is pointless.  You will start building the cache as your computer makes DNS queries.

The only reason you would flush the DNS cache is if you are getting stale records.